# Canvas to data url not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, data-url

I have a function that takes an img-element and returns a data url. This works like 7/10 times and returns a blank image 3/10 times. I view the created data url through my browser(chrome) and use the same images so I know that this function is returning broken images. Can anyone spot why?

```
function imgToDataURL(img) {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = img.naturalWidth;
    canvas.height = img.naturalHeight;
    var c = canvas.getContext('2d');
    c.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    dataurl = canvas.toDataURL();
    return dataurl;
}

$(function() {
    img = new Image();
    img.crossOrigin = '';
    img.onload = function() {
        newimg = new Image();
        newimg.onload = function() {
            document.body.appendChild(newimg);
        }
        newimg.src = imgToDataURL(img);
    }
    img.src = 'https://somedomain.s3.amazonaws.com/someimg.png';
});
```

This example works most of the time but sometimes ends with a large white rectangle instead of the image.

Comment: Note that for security reasons, canvas source images must be hosted on the same domain as the page that's serving it.  So, if your img.src is other-domain and you write that other-domain image to canvas then canvas.toDataURL will fail.

Comment: I have set this up so I can read images from the domain in question using CORS.

Comment: Just curious...why are you running img through canvas?  Couldn't you just create an html img-element with .src='https://somedomain.s3.amazonaws.com/someimg.png'

Comment: your img.crossOrigin should be img.crossOrigin="anonymous"

Comment: It's to be used with some image processing where the images may be processed and then the result of that may be processed again. So it's convenient to turn them into data urls at first sight. I am not getting any security errors. That was my last headache.

Answer (score 3):

You have to **wait for images to load before drawing them** using `.drawImage` function.
Only after the image is loaded by the browser you can call your `imgToDataURL` function.

Something like this:

```
var image_sources = ["img1.png", "img2.png", "..."];

for(var i=0; i<image_sources.length; i++) {
    var new_img = document.createElement("img");
    new_img.onload = function() {
       imgToDataURL(this);
    };
    new_img.src = image_sources[i];
}
```

Comment: I wish this was the problem but I am already doing this.The imgToDataURL is always called with loaded images.

Comment: @user2073343 can u make a jsfiddle demonstrating the problem? There is nothing wrong with the code you posted

Comment: @user2073343 in that case, can you provide an actual working example of your problem? The above is obviously incomplete as we don't see when/how imgToDataUrl is called.

Comment: It's called in the same way as the above given exempel. I am thinking if the size of the images is causing problems. The images can be several megabytes large. I know that the input to the image is intact. It's the output that's broken.

Comment: @user2073343 No, `imgToDataURL` is not called anywhere in your example.  Obviously you are experiencing a problem, but if you don't provide the context in which `imgToDataURL` is called then your example is incomplete.

Comment: I have added an example now.

Comment: @user2073343 This is the correct answer.  The updated code very clearly shows `imgToDataURL(img)` being called outside of the `onload` event.  Please note that making the call after you assign the `onload` event is *not* the same as actually waiting for it to load.  You have to put it inside the `onload` event.

Comment: It is within the first onload event where I load the image that I want to turn it into a data url.